# Segmentation fault after insert to map (private atribute) in public metod

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I really cant figure out this, please help.

In my class is:

```
private:
map<int, int> TEST;
.
.
.
void CClass::testMap() {
    TEST[5] = 3;
}
```

After method testMap call i get Segmentation fault. Real code is more complicated with 10 other classes but i dont understand why this doesnt work. There arent any pointers, primitive types have no copy constructor or assigment overload I have absolutely no idea where is the problem. Please help, every idea will helpfull

Comment: This is perfectly fine. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: the code won't crash if there would be only that line. can you come up with smallest possible code that causes the program to crash?

Comment: That code should not be producing a segfault, can you post all of the code related to the std::map?

Comment: Try valgrind. Also, I don't know for sure, but usually when I have a segfault and I don't know the source, I have a bad alias. Check your pointers and your delete and free calls. Make sure you aren't keeping references to freed memory.

Comment: Yes, Valgrind gave me 5 errors, I havent created destructors yet, but i am going to. Anyway there are pointers in map only in other classes, not in the cless in which i get the SIGSEGV. I didnt know it may affects this class. Ill try to create the destructors.

Comment: Well, I can upload whole source, in fact, its homework for C++ course at university, but my mentor really doesnt help me with this :( And I cant get through the error. Is here anybody willing to take a look on it?

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question is correct. Look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer given the (lack of) information in the question.